# Scope of return Values of function if the type is pointer

Tags: c

```
int* getINT ()
{
    int y =10;
    int *x = &y;
    return x;
}
char* getARRAY()
{
    char str[]= "Hai";
    return str;
}

int Main(void)
{   
    char *ptr;
    int *result;
    result = getINT();
    printf ("%d\n", *result);
    ptr = getARRAY();
    printf("%s", ptr);
}
```

In the main function *result holds the value of 10 while ptr has garbage value. My doubt is why *str loses scope while *x don't lose scope

Comment: both are undefined behaviour, you should not rely on the "working" function.

Comment: A matter of coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

both are invalid and that `result` is still 10 is more of a coincidence than anything.
Both times the values in the function only exist while in the function, as soon as you leave the function they cease to exist, because both are allocated on the stack within the current stack frame of the function. If the function returns, the stack frame will be removed and if you call another function the space will be reused.
So any pointers to data on the stack of the function are basically useless outside of the function, since chances are pretty high, that the data will be overwritten by the time you try to access it.

Comment: Thanks Now i got it. Actually , I was confused when i got 10.Now I understand that it was just a coincidence

Answer (score 1):

When you return the address of a local variable, that variable goes out of scope and the memory location used by that variable can be reused for other purposes.  Attempting to dereference such a pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Your code may crash, it may show unexpected results, or it may appear to work properly.  Making a seemingly unrelated change to your code such as adding an extra unused variable or an added/removed `printf` can cause that behavior to change.

As to what is *probably* happening, at the time you populate `result` in main, no other function has yet been called, so the stack space used by `y` in `getINT` has not been overwritten yet.  In the next statement, you dereference that pointer to get the value of `y`.  Because this is done before any function is called, the value of `y` has not yet been overwritten so you are able to get the value.

In the case of `ptr`, you pass that pointer directly to `printf`.  The act of calling `printf` writes to the stack and overwrites the memory previously occupied by `str` in `getARRAY`.

If you were to add `printf("hello\n");` before printing `*result` you would likely not print `10` for its value.  Similarly, if you copied the string pointed to by `ptr` in a loop to a local variable in `main` (without calling another function), you would likely recover the string `Hai`.

Again though, you can't depend on this behavior.  Some compilers may opt to clear out what was on the stack after a function returns.  Similarly, changing the optimization level could result in a function being inlined so there are no stack changes.  That's all part of **undefined behavior**.